# What is the range of Random.nextDouble in Scala?

Tags: scala, random

The  Scaladoc page for **Random** ( http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/Random.html ) specifies that **nextDouble** "Returns the next pseudorandom, uniformly distributed double value between 0.0 and 1.0 from this random number generator's sequence."

Pretty glaringly, it leaves out "inclusion". For instance, are value 0.0 and 1.0 possible? If so, which one (or both)? For instance, if I am dividing by this number, I'd really want to make sure that 0 was not a returned value. In other cases, I might not want 1.0. Quite obviously, this is hard to get via testing, as there about *10^15* values between 0.0 and 1.0.

Which is it? Please note, since not everyone can remember which of "(" and "[" means "inclusive", please just say "includes X".

Comment: side note: 1.0 is exclusive but because of internal representation of floating point numbers it can happen that a value near to 1.0 is represented as 1.0 when you do some arithmetic with it... (there is a Java puzzle on this but I can't find it now).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is due to the fact that `scala.util.Random` is a very thin wrapper around `java.util.Random` ([see the source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.9.2/src/library/scala/util/Random.scala#L1)), which is documented [in sufficient detail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextDouble()):

> The general contract of nextDouble is that one double value, chosen (approximately) uniformly from the range 0.0d (**inclusive**) to 1.0d (**exclusive**), is pseudorandomly generated and returned.

Comment: nextDouble() is an incredibly important function: this needs to be documented in the language "scaladocs" itself in EXCRUCIATING detail. Relying on the fact that it's a wrapper around a Java function, q.v. is a very bad idea, for surely there will be a case some day where it WON'T be based on a Java function. In any case, thanks for the answer!